# Working out average time

Tags: php, time, average

I have an array of times as below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00:00:04
    [1] => 00:00:05
    [2] => 00:00:02
    [3] => 00:00:09
    [4] => 00:00:03
    []...
)
```

And I am trying to work out the average time using the code below:

```
foreach($times as $t) {          
    $unixtime += strtotime($t);      
}      

$unixtime = $unixtime / count($times);  

echo "Unix Time: " . $unixtime . "<br />";  
echo "Formatted: " . date("h:i:s",$unixtime) . "<p/>";
```

But the output I am getting is:

> Unix Time: 1345669204.37 
>   Formatted: 12:00:04

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the date format string from `h:i:s` to `H:i:s` it should start working.

The `h` format is used for 12hr clock and starts at `12` for midnight; the 24hr clock starts at `00`.